Upper bound on the chromatic number of a graph in terms of induced subgraphs on vertices at a distance $i$ from vertex $x_0$
Let $G$ be a finite, connected graph and $x_0 \in V(G)$. For each $i \in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$, define $V_i$ as follows:
$$V_i = \{v \in V(G) | \ \text{dist}_G(x_0,v) = i\}, $$
where dist$_G(x_0,v)$ denotes the length of the shortest path in $G$ from $x_0$ to some $v \in V(G)$. 
Prove that
$$\chi(G) \leq \max_{r \in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}}(\chi(G[V_r] + \chi(G[V_{r+1}])).$$
How do I approach this? Any hints to begin with would be very helpful; I've tried using some well-known bounds and results but haven't made much progress.

Try to explicitely construct a coloring

Throughout this answer I'll use $V_i$ to refer to both $V_i$ and $G[V_i]$. It should be obvious from context which one I'm actually referring to

Let $d$ be the maximum distance a vertex has with $x_0$, then the sets $V_0,\cdots,V_d$ form a partition of $V(G)$ with the property that every $V_i$ only has neighbors in $V_{i-1}$ and $V_{i+1}$. We'll inductively construct a coloring of $G$ with $c=\max_{r\geq0}(\chi(V_r)+\chi(V_{r+1}))$ colors. We'll properly color each $V_i$ with $\chi(V_i)$ colors, ignoring the colors used to color $V_{i-1}$. We we'll always have at least that many colors, since we colored $V_{i-1}$ with $\chi(V_{i-1})$ colors, so we have at least $c-\chi(V_{i-1})\geq \chi(V_{i})$ colors left, by definition of $c$. Now, suppose the edge $uv$ was monochromatic, then they are in different $V_{i}$'s, since each $V_i$ was colored properly; if they are in different $V_i$'s then they must be adjacent $V_i$'s, since those are the only ones with edges in-between them, w.l.o.g. suppose $u\in V_i$ and $v\in V_{i+1}$, this is a contradiction, since the set of colors of $V_{i+1}$ is different to those used for $V_i$. Therefore, there's no monochromatic edges, and so the coloring is proper.

Notice that we didn't actually use that the graph is finite, we didn't even need $d$ to be finite, we only needed connectedness
